# Capturing a picture from default camera and setting it as wallpaper

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to capture a picture from the default camera and set it as wallpaper, using code from tutorials. I'm using an image button for taking the picture from the camera and a normal button to set that picture as wallpaper. Unfortunately, the camera button is not responding to clicking it. How do I fix this?

My sdk version is "adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321", and here's my code.

Java code for camera[1]:

```
package com.office.razer;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Camera extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{    
ImageButton ib;
Button b;
ImageView iv;
Intent i;
Bitmap bmp;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id._iv1);
        b=(Button) findViewById(R.id._b1);
        ib=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id._ib1);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id._b1:
            try {
                getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmp);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case R.id._ib1:

            i=new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i,0);
            break;
            }
        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
        bmp=(Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
    }   
    }
```

and xml code [2]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/_iv1"
        android:layout_width="166dp"
        android:layout_height="166dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/_ib1"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_cab_background_bottom_holo_dark" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/_b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />
"

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the menu java code[3]:

```
package com.office.razer;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {
    String classes[]={"MainActivity","Togglesw","Email","Camera","Contacts","Messages","WhatsAPP"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,classes));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String cheese=classes[position];
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Class ourclass;
        try {
            ourclass = Class.forName("com.office.razer."+cheese);
            Intent ourIntent=new Intent(Menu.this,ourclass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

manifest.xml[4]:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.office.razer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.office.razer.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
          <activity
            android:name=".Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.office.razer.Menu" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".Togglesw"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.office.razer.TOGGLESW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> <activity
            android:name=".Email"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.office.razer.EMAIL" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name=".Camera"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.office.razer.CAMERA" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: 1. A question title should be a question. 2. Tell us what coding language / platform your using. 3. I can't read code formatted like that. 4. I don't think you actually asked a question here

Comment: If you're going to ask a question here, please show more effort with asking the actual question. Read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page to see best practices for asking a question; for specific things I noticed, please use relevant tags (`java` is far more helpful than `camera`/`wallpaper` since Java coders will know the question is something they can try to help with), please format your code in a readable manner, and please try to ask your question as clearly as possible.